# Powershell file Renaming + Date

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rename a set of files which will add yesterday's date to the file instead of keeping today's date. I started the powershell but need some assistance
Thank you

```
$Newdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$newpath = "c:\test\business\"

Get-ChildItem $newpath -Recurse -Force -Filter "*.csv"  | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 
 "_","$Newdate"}
```

Files right now

- test_Today's date
  performance_Today's date improvement+Today's date

I want to keep the name only and replace todays date to yesterday
test_yesterday's date
performance_yesterday's date
improvement+yesterday's date

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? The file name you present doesn't help much as example.

```
PS /~> $now=([datetime]::Now).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
PS /~> $new=([datetime]::Now).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
PS /~> "test_2021-04-15performance_2021-04-15improvement+2021-04-15" -replace $now,$new
test_2021-04-14performance_2021-04-14improvement+2021-04-14
```